# Identifying Subordinate Clauses

Tags: clauses

hello im having serious trouble identifying the clauses in these sentences.

> A healthy diet should be a balanced one with a variety of foods from each of the food groups. Obviously, these should be eaten in the right proportions.
>
> Being the bodys main source of energy, starchy foods such as potatoes, rice and pasta should make up a third of your diet. Try to select the whole grain variety of these essential carbohydrates.

My problem is that all my references and resources always refer to a 3rd party. like

He will
They do
She did

but nowhere is my references does it use the word your.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Scott! It's unclear what your question is. Do you want to find all the subordinate clauses in the text? How does that relate to third-party constructions?

Comment: yes sorry that is what i mean i want to find the subourdinate clauses in those sentences. what i mean in that all my reference materiel the subject is always someone else but in these examples the subject is me and its thrown me off.

Comment: Why should it, Scott? [This](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm) can help.

Comment: One really can't discover what your problems are. Try to think about it and put forward one single problem. I think it would be too much to answer all your questions in one post.

Answer (score 1):

The four sentences of your text contain no subordinate clauses. A subordinate clause must contain

- 1 a subordinating conjunction (when, as, while, because, although etc)
- 2 a subject
- 3 a verb

Answer (score 1):

Clauses have a subject and verb.  When you have a single sentence with two subject-verb pairs, then you are possibly dealing with subordinate clauses.  But none of your sentences have more than one clause.

This might be potentially confusing:

> Being the body's main source of energy, starchy foods such as potatoes, rice and pasta should make up a third of your diet.

You might think *being* here is a verb, but it's not (*-ing* words are not verbs - they can be *part of* verbs if preceded by a form of *to be*).  So the *phrase* "Being the body's main source of energy" has no subject-verb pair and it is not a *clause*.

[This article](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinate_clause.htm) explains that subordinate clauses often are preceded by the following common conjunctions or relative pronouns:

> after, although, as, because, before, even if, even though, if,
>   provided, rather than, since, so that, than, though, unless, until,
>   whether, while
>
> how, that, what, when, where, which, who, whom, whose, why

Answer (score -1):

A healthy diet *(subject)*

should be *(verb)*

a balanced one *(object, "one" here refers back to "diet")*

**with a variety of foods from each of the food groups**. *(subordinate clause)*

**Obviously,** *(adverbial subordinate clause)*

these *(subject,"these" refers back to "foods" in the previous sentence)*

should be eaten *(verb phrase)*

**in the right proportions.** *(subordinate clause)*

**Being the body's main source of energy,** *(subordinate clause)*

starchy foods  *(subject)*

**such as potatoes, rice and pasta** *(subordinate clause)*

should make up *(verb phrase)*

a third of your diet. *(object)*

Try to select *(verb phrase - subject (you) is omitted in imperative tense)*

the whole grain variety *(object noun phrase)*

**of these essential carbohydrates.** *(subordinate clause)*

Comment: A clause is a sentence with a subject and a verb that is added to a main clause, What you see as clauses (in bold print) are everything  but no clauses.

Comment: [This](http://magoosh.com/gmat/2012/gmat-grammar-adjectival-phrases-and-clauses/) is a nice explanation of the difference between phrases and clauses.  These are phrases.